# Nested Structure formatting in C

Tags: c, syntax, structure, naming, unions

I come across a nested structure & union with the following syntax. I am not sure how the following syntax needs to be corrected.

typedef **struct 1**
{
..
..
union
{
struct
{
..
..
}**var1**;
struct
{
...
...
...
}**var2**;
}
..
..
}**name_to_struct1**

Can someone explain what is wrong here, and how the syntax must be given. I see the error thrown is **"struct 1" has no member named var1**

NOTE: The compiler I am using is not a C11, so this type of unnamed structure/union should be avoided.

Comment: I would need a bit more context, because for me

"typedef struct { 
    union {
        struct {
            int a;
            double b;
        }var1;
        struct {
            int c;
            double d;
        }var2;
    };
} name_to_struct1;

printf("%d\n", asd.var1.a);"

this works. What is the compiler?

Comment: C96 compiler. Here to avoid compiler warning there are some extensions used, but now I need to remove those extensions and format this syntax in order to build it without any issues(warnings)

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of out of ideas here, I have never heard about this compiler, cannot find anything about it online. So, my last idea, is the following: name the union as well:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    union {
        struct {
            int a;
            double b;
        } var1;
        struct {
            int c;
            double d;
        } var2;
    } uni;
} name_to_struct1;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    name_to_struct1 asd;
    asd.uni.var1.a = 1;
    printf("%d\n", asd.uni.var1.a);
    return 0;
}
```

If unnamed structs and unions are not allowed, maybe this could help.